# Creating the new Directories in the ANT Apply Operation

Tags: ant, minify

I am trying to minify the css files in a directory and place the minified items into another directory. I already have:

```
    <target name="css.minify">
        <apply executable="java" parallel="false" force="true" dest="FDN/css/min">
            <fileset dir="FDN/css" includes="**/*.css"/>
            <arg value="-jar"/>
            <arg path="lib/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
            <srcfile/>
            <arg value="-o"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="*.css" to="*-min.css"/>
            <targetfile/>
        </apply>
    </target>
```

This works fine when the directory structure in FDN/css/min is the same as FDN/css. However, if a new directory is added a FileNotFound occurs because it does not exist in the destination.

How can I force the directory to be created if it does not already exist?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the dirs **before** you execute the `apply` task.

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
    <touch mkdirs="true">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.css"/>
        </fileset>
        <regexpmapper from="^(.*)/[^/]*$$" to="dest/\1/.tmp" handledirsep="true"/>
    </touch>
    <delete>
      <fileset dir="dest" includes="**/.tmp"/>
    </delete>
```

It's based on [an answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028031/127035) to a different question.